# Leaderboard - No public scores for this game

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I've setup google play game services to my app and added a leaderboard. I've added the game id and leaderboard id in code. And now both the application and game are published.

Code used to launch leaderboard

```
 if(mclient.isConnected())
                   {
                   startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                            getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_quiz_app)),
                            1);
                   }
```

This is how scores are updated

```
if(mclient.isConnected())
       {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.leaderboard_quiz_app),
            Long.valueOf(score));
       }
```

Even after playing the game n number of times, scores are not updating in the leaderboard and this is what is getting displayed, in the leaderboard:

> There are no public highscores for this game

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Also tried by making the user's profile as public and disabled tamper protection in leaderboards, checked with OAuth2 Client ID and SHA-1 fingerprint. But still the same message is being shown. Please let me know the issue. Thankyou!

Comment: Based from this [forum](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/64882-gpgs-leaderboard-there-are-no-public-high-scores-for-this-game/), you should create a listener function to allow `gameNetwork.request()` the opportunity to return information back to you about the success of the call. You should also look at your device's console log (adb logcat with no additional parameters) and see if you're getting any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this issue by upgrading the following libraries in Android Studio(Tools | Android | SDK Manager)

- Android SDK Platform Tools
- Google Play Services
- Google Repository